# Is there any working example with flutter/Cognito/AWSIoT?

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, mqtt, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

for my connected chicken coop (https://www.twitch.tv/cloudaryer) based mainly on AWS IoT things with different topics, I would like to develop an flutter app to control and get status from the coop by establishing a websocket between the app and AWS Iot Core.

For such task, I've browsed many sites, code examples based on **MQTT**, **flutter_cognito_plugin**, **aws_iot**... to get some good info to start the project.
However, none of them are working, obsolete libs, compiling errors when you upgrade libs to newer tags...

**I've just managed to establish a good auth process with Cognito and collect accessKey, secretAccessKey & sessionToken**.
I'm stuck now to connect to my AWS IoT websocket and be able to pubish and read on specific topics.

If you have any good examples or ideas to establich such AWS IoT websocket connection, I'm really interested in as I'm going nuts with this issue ^^

Thanks you all for your potential help ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately asking for links to examples is off topic for Stack Overflow. Show what you've tried and describe the errors/problems and somebody may be able to help you fix it.

Comment: Have you got it working? I appreciate your reply, because I am now standing exactly in front of the same exact problematic step.